# Setting a Whenever job at different hours every day

Tags: ruby, whenever

I'm trying to set a Whenever job that should be executed 2 times a day, exactly at 11am and 11pm. Is there any way to do it with only one block? I mean something like this:

```
every :day, :at => ['11am','11pm'] do
  runner "Task"
end
```

Comment: This is actually possible in the newest version, as written here.

Comment: @mltsy did you intend to include documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're concerned about DRYness of your code, then how about this?

```
['11am','11pm'].each do |at|
  every :day, :at => at  do
    runner "Task"
  end  
end
```

Comment: For posterity: this is actually possible as written in the question  in the newest version, so this isn't necessary (in case you want to update the answer).

Answer (score 10):

#### Whenever now supports the syntax proposed in the question.

Just pass an array to the `:at` option.

```
every :day, at: ["11am", "11pm"] do
  runner "Task"
end
```